# How to generate random DateTimes with nscala-time

Tags: scala

I need to generate random DateTimes with nscala-time.

I've found [an SO answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771845/generating-random-date-time-in-java-joda-time), for jodatime. I haven't managed to translate the answer to nscala-time though.

Here is what I want to do:

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
val startTimestamp = DateTime(Random.nextLong(1000))
val endTimestamp = DateTime(Random.nextLong(1000) + 1000)
```

The problem is that, in nscala-time, DateTime's companion object doesn't expose any `apply` method.

By the way: would you recommend using another time framework for Scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bypass nscala-time on this one and use the `new` keyword:

```
val startTimestamp = new DateTime(Random.nextLong(1000))
val endTimestamp = new DateTime(Random.nextLong(1000) + 1000)
```

The return type are the same.