# Generate a random LocalDate with java.time

Tags: java, mysql, date, random, java-time

I'm writing some code to populate a MySQL database with random data for testing purposes. I need to populate a `DATE` column with random dates from 1970-2015.

Here's the relevant method:

```
public Date dateGenerator() throws Exception {
    Random ry = new Random();
    Random rm = new Random();
    Random rd = new Random();
    int year = 1969 + ry.nextInt(2015-1969+1);
    int month = 1 + rm.nextInt(12);
    int day = 1 + rm.nextInt(31);

    if (month==2 && day>28){
        day = day - 3;            
    } else {
        if((month%2==0 && month != 8 ) && day==31 ){
            day = day -1;
        }
    }
}
```

My purpose is to create three random integers (for day, month, year) and somehow combine them into some Date object to pass to the database. But the database rejects everything I try to feed it.

It would be very educational for me if you can supply me with a suggestion based in the newest `java.time` library if this is possible.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771845/generating-random-date-time-in-java-joda-time

Comment: OK I think it works just fine :) Thank you for your kind contributions, I was stuck for hours with this... After the conversion (which I made it within the method) though it asked for another one within the `main` class. Just a further note :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A simple way is to convert the minimum and maximum date to their corresponding epoch day, generate a random integer between those two values and finally convert it back to a `LocalDate`. The epoch day is obtained with [`toEpochDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay--) which is the count of days since 1970-01-01 (ISO).

The problem with generating a random year, then month and then day is that you have a small chance of falling with an invalid date (like 31st of February). Also, taking a random epoch day guarantees a uniform distribution across all possible dates.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    long minDay = LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 1).toEpochDay();
    long maxDay = LocalDate.of(2015, 12, 31).toEpochDay();
    long randomDay = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(minDay, maxDay);
    LocalDate randomDate = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(randomDay);
    System.out.println(randomDate);
}
```

Note that since the minimum date is actually the very first, you could replace it with 0.

To convert this `LocalDate` into a `java.sql.Date`, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29168494/1743880):

```
java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(randomDate);
```

Comment: It would be a slight improvement in readability to use `LocalDate.ofEpochDay(0)` to get `minDay`.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(1970, Month.JANUARY, 1);
    long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, LocalDate.now());
    LocalDate randomDate = start.plusDays(new Random().nextInt((int) days + 1));
    System.out.println(randomDate);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Is there a way to convert  `LocalDate` to Date in order to feed it to the database? or maybe alter the statement? (though I 've tried and failed this way)

Comment: You can try Basil's earlys suggestion of using java.sql.Date.valueOf(randomDate), however, I'm pretty sure most databases will accept it if you use  randomDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE) in your insert statement.